# RuntimeError: Expected number of channels in input to be divisible by num_groups, but got input of shape [64, 16, 32, 32] and num_groups=32

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, image-classification, batch-normalization, efficientnet

I have EfficientNet working fine on my dataset. Now, I changed all the batch norm layers into group norm layers. I have already done this process with other networks like vgg16 and resnet18 and all was ok. On EfficientNet I have this error `RuntimeError: Expected number of channels in input to be divisible by num_groups, but got input of shape [64, 16, 32, 32] and num_groups=32`
Basically I have done this:

```
efficientnet_b0 = torchvision.models.efficientnet_b0(pretrained=False)

efficientnet_b0.classifier = nn.Linear(in_features=1280, out_features=10, bias=True)


efficientnet_b0.features[0][1] = nn.GroupNorm(32, 32)
efficientnet_b0.features[1][0].block[0][1] = nn.GroupNorm(32, 32)
efficientnet_b0.features[1][0].block[2][1] = nn.GroupNorm(32, 16)
efficientnet_b0.features[2][0].block[0][1] = nn.GroupNorm(32, 96)
efficientnet_b0.features[2][0].block[1][1] = nn.GroupNorm(32, 96)
efficientnet_b0.features[2][0].block[3][1] = nn.GroupNorm(32, 24)
efficientnet_b0.features[2][1].block[0][1] = nn.GroupNorm(32, 144)
efficientnet_b0.features[2][1].block[1][1] = nn.GroupNorm(32, 144)
efficientnet_b0.features[2][1].block[3][1] = nn.GroupNorm(32, 24)
efficientnet_b0.features[3][0].block[0][1] = nn.GroupNorm(32, 144)
efficientnet_b0.features[3][0].block[1][1] = nn.GroupNorm(32, 144)
efficientnet_b0.features[3][0].block[3][1] = nn.GroupNorm(32, 40)
efficientnet_b0.features[3][1].block[0][1] = nn.GroupNorm(32, 240)
efficientnet_b0.features[3][1].block[1][1] = nn.GroupNorm(32, 240)
efficientnet_b0.features[3][1].block[3][1] = nn.GroupNorm(32, 40)
efficientnet_b0.features[4][0].block[0][1] = nn.GroupNorm(32, 240)
efficientnet_b0.features[4][0].block[1][1] = nn.GroupNorm(32, 240)
efficientnet_b0.features[4][0].block[3][1] = nn.GroupNorm(32, 80)
efficientnet_b0.features[4][1].block[0][1] = nn.GroupNorm(32, 480)
efficientnet_b0.features[4][1].block[1][1] = nn.GroupNorm(32, 480)
efficientnet_b0.features[4][1].block[3][1] = nn.GroupNorm(32, 80)
efficientnet_b0.features[4][2].block[0][1] = nn.GroupNorm(32, 480)
efficientnet_b0.features[4][2].block[1][1] = nn.GroupNorm(32, 480)
efficientnet_b0.features[4][2].block[3][1] = nn.GroupNorm(32, 80)
efficientnet_b0.features[5][0].block[0][1] = nn.GroupNorm(32, 480)
efficientnet_b0.features[5][0].block[1][1] = nn.GroupNorm(32, 480)
efficientnet_b0.features[5][0].block[3][1] = nn.GroupNorm(32, 112)
efficientnet_b0.features[5][1].block[0][1] = nn.GroupNorm(32, 672)
efficientnet_b0.features[5][1].block[1][1] = nn.GroupNorm(32, 672)
efficientnet_b0.features[5][1].block[3][1] = nn.GroupNorm(32, 112)
efficientnet_b0.features[5][2].block[0][1] = nn.GroupNorm(32, 672)
efficientnet_b0.features[5][2].block[1][1] = nn.GroupNorm(32, 672)
efficientnet_b0.features[5][2].block[3][1] = nn.GroupNorm(32, 112)
efficientnet_b0.features[6][0].block[0][1] = nn.GroupNorm(32, 672)
efficientnet_b0.features[6][0].block[1][1] = nn.GroupNorm(32, 672)
efficientnet_b0.features[6][0].block[3][1] = nn.GroupNorm(32, 192)
efficientnet_b0.features[6][1].block[0][1] = nn.GroupNorm(32, 1152)
efficientnet_b0.features[6][1].block[1][1] = nn.GroupNorm(32, 1152)
efficientnet_b0.features[6][1].block[3][1] = nn.GroupNorm(32, 192)
efficientnet_b0.features[6][2].block[0][1] = nn.GroupNorm(32, 1152)
efficientnet_b0.features[6][2].block[1][1] = nn.GroupNorm(32, 1152)
efficientnet_b0.features[6][2].block[3][1] = nn.GroupNorm(32, 192)
efficientnet_b0.features[6][3].block[0][1] = nn.GroupNorm(32, 1152)
efficientnet_b0.features[6][3].block[1][1] = nn.GroupNorm(32, 1152)
efficientnet_b0.features[6][3].block[3][1] = nn.GroupNorm(32, 192)
efficientnet_b0.features[7][0].block[0][1] = nn.GroupNorm(32, 1152)
efficientnet_b0.features[7][0].block[1][1] = nn.GroupNorm(32, 1152)
efficientnet_b0.features[7][0].block[3][1] = nn.GroupNorm(32, 320)
efficientnet_b0.features[8][1] = nn.GroupNorm(32, 1280)
```

The original efficientnet is this:

```
EfficientNet(
  (features): Sequential(
    (0): ConvNormActivation(
      (0): Conv2d(3, 32, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(2, 2), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
      (1): BatchNorm2d(32, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
      (2): SiLU(inplace=True)
    )
    (1): Sequential(
      (0): MBConv(
        (block): Sequential(
          (0): ConvNormActivation(
            (0): Conv2d(32, 32, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), groups=32, bias=False)
            (1): BatchNorm2d(32, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
            (2): SiLU(inplace=True)
          )
          (1): SqueezeExcitation(
            (avgpool): AdaptiveAvgPool2d(output_size=1)
            (fc1): Conv2d(32, 8, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1))
            (fc2): Conv2d(8, 32, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1))
            (activation): SiLU(inplace=True)
            (scale_activation): Sigmoid()
          )
          (2): ConvNormActivation(
            (0): Conv2d(32, 16, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
            (1): BatchNorm2d(16, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
          )
        )
        (stochastic_depth): StochasticDepth(p=0.0, mode=row)
      )
    )
    (2): Sequential(
      (0): MBConv(
        (block): Sequential(
          (0): ConvNormActivation(
            (0): Conv2d(16, 96, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
            (1): BatchNorm2d(96, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
            (2): SiLU(inplace=True)
          )
          (1): ConvNormActivation(
            (0): Conv2d(96, 96, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(2, 2), padding=(1, 1), groups=96, bias=False)
            (1): BatchNorm2d(96, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
            (2): SiLU(inplace=True)
          )
          (2): SqueezeExcitation(
            (avgpool): AdaptiveAvgPool2d(output_size=1)
            (fc1): Conv2d(96, 4, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1))
            (fc2): Conv2d(4, 96, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1))
            (activation): SiLU(inplace=True)
            (scale_activation): Sigmoid()
          )
          (3): ConvNormActivation(
            (0): Conv2d(96, 24, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
            (1): BatchNorm2d(24, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
          )
        )
        (stochastic_depth): StochasticDepth(p=0.0125, mode=row)
      )
      (1): MBConv(
        (block): Sequential(
          (0): ConvNormActivation(
            (0): Conv2d(24, 144, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
            (1): BatchNorm2d(144, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
            (2): SiLU(inplace=True)
          )
          (1): ConvNormActivation(
            (0): Conv2d(144, 144, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), groups=144, bias=False)
            (1): BatchNorm2d(144, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
            (2): SiLU(inplace=True)
          )
          (2): SqueezeExcitation(
            (avgpool): AdaptiveAvgPool2d(output_size=1)
            (fc1): Conv2d(144, 6, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1))
            (fc2): Conv2d(6, 144, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1))
            (activation): SiLU(inplace=True)
            (scale_activation): Sigmoid()
          )
          (3): ConvNormActivation(
            (0): Conv2d(144, 24, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
            (1): BatchNorm2d(24, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
          )
        )
        (stochastic_depth): StochasticDepth(p=0.025, mode=row)
      )
    )
    (3): Sequential(
      (0): MBConv(
        (block): Sequential(
          (0): ConvNormActivation(
            (0): Conv2d(24, 144, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
            (1): BatchNorm2d(144, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
            (2): SiLU(inplace=True)
          )
          (1): ConvNormActivation(
            (0): Conv2d(144, 144, kernel_size=(5, 5), stride=(2, 2), padding=(2, 2), groups=144, bias=False)
            (1): BatchNorm2d(144, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
            (2): SiLU(inplace=True)
          )
          (2): SqueezeExcitation(
            (avgpool): AdaptiveAvgPool2d(output_size=1)
            (fc1): Conv2d(144, 6, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1))
            (fc2): Conv2d(6, 144, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1))
            (activation): SiLU(inplace=True)
            (scale_activation): Sigmoid()
          )
          (3): ConvNormActivation(
            (0): Conv2d(144, 40, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
            (1): BatchNorm2d(40, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
          )
        )
        (stochastic_depth): StochasticDepth(p=0.037500000000000006, mode=row)
      )
      (1): MBConv(
        (block): Sequential(
          (0): ConvNormActivation(
            (0): Conv2d(40, 240, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
            (1): BatchNorm2d(240, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
            (2): SiLU(inplace=True)
          )
          (1): ConvNormActivation(
            (0): Conv2d(240, 240, kernel_size=(5, 5), stride=(1, 1), padding=(2, 2), groups=240, bias=False)
            (1): BatchNorm2d(240, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
            (2): SiLU(inplace=True)
          )
          (2): SqueezeExcitation(
            (avgpool): AdaptiveAvgPool2d(output_size=1)
            (fc1): Conv2d(240, 10, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1))
            (fc2): Conv2d(10, 240, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1))
            (activation): SiLU(inplace=True)
            (scale_activation): Sigmoid()
          )
          (3): ConvNormActivation(
            (0): Conv2d(240, 40, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
            (1): BatchNorm2d(40, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
          )
        )
        (stochastic_depth): StochasticDepth(p=0.05, mode=row)
      )
    )
    (4): Sequential(
      (0): MBConv(
        (block): Sequential(
          (0): ConvNormActivation(
            (0): Conv2d(40, 240, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
            (1): BatchNorm2d(240, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
            (2): SiLU(inplace=True)
          )
          (1): ConvNormActivation(
            (0): Conv2d(240, 240, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(2, 2), padding=(1, 1), groups=240, bias=False)
            (1): BatchNorm2d(240, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
            (2): SiLU(inplace=True)
          )
          (2): SqueezeExcitation(
            (avgpool): AdaptiveAvgPool2d(output_size=1)
            (fc1): Conv2d(240, 10, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1))
            (fc2): Conv2d(10, 240, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1))
            (activation): SiLU(inplace=True)
            (scale_activation): Sigmoid()
          )
          (3): ConvNormActivation(
            (0): Conv2d(240, 80, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
            (1): BatchNorm2d(80, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
          )
        )
        (stochastic_depth): StochasticDepth(p=0.0625, mode=row)
      )
      (1): MBConv(
        (block): Sequential(
          (0): ConvNormActivation(
            (0): Conv2d(80, 480, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
            (1): BatchNorm2d(480, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
            (2): SiLU(inplace=True)
          )
          (1): ConvNormActivation(
            (0): Conv2d(480, 480, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), groups=480, bias=False)
            (1): BatchNorm2d(480, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
            (2): SiLU(inplace=True)
          )
          (2): SqueezeExcitation(
            (avgpool): AdaptiveAvgPool2d(output_size=1)
            (fc1): Conv2d(480, 20, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1))
            (fc2): Conv2d(20, 480, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1))
            (activation): SiLU(inplace=True)
            (scale_activation): Sigmoid()
          )
          (3): ConvNormActivation(
            (0): Conv2d(480, 80, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
            (1): BatchNorm2d(80, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
          )
        )
        (stochastic_depth): StochasticDepth(p=0.07500000000000001, mode=row)
      )
      (2): MBConv(
        (block): Sequential(
          (0): ConvNormActivation(
            (0): Conv2d(80, 480, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
            (1): BatchNorm2d(480, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
            (2): SiLU(inplace=True)
          )
          (1): ConvNormActivation(
            (0): Conv2d(480, 480, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), groups=480, bias=False)
            (1): BatchNorm2d(480, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
            (2): SiLU(inplace=True)
          )
          (2): SqueezeExcitation(
            (avgpool): AdaptiveAvgPool2d(output_size=1)
            (fc1): Conv2d(480, 20, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1))
            (fc2): Conv2d(20, 480, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1))
            (activation): SiLU(inplace=True)
            (scale_activation): Sigmoid()
          )
          (3): ConvNormActivation(
            (0): Conv2d(480, 80, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
            (1): BatchNorm2d(80, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
          )
        )
        (stochastic_depth): StochasticDepth(p=0.08750000000000001, mode=row)
      )
    )
    (5): Sequential(
      (0): MBConv(
        (block): Sequential(
          (0): ConvNormActivation(
            (0): Conv2d(80, 480, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
            (1): BatchNorm2d(480, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
            (2): SiLU(inplace=True)
          )
          (1): ConvNormActivation(
            (0): Conv2d(480, 480, kernel_size=(5, 5), stride=(1, 1), padding=(2, 2), groups=480, bias=False)
            (1): BatchNorm2d(480, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
            (2): SiLU(inplace=True)
          )
          (2): SqueezeExcitation(
            (avgpool): AdaptiveAvgPool2d(output_size=1)
            (fc1): Conv2d(480, 20, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1))
            (fc2): Conv2d(20, 480, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1))
            (activation): SiLU(inplace=True)
            (scale_activation): Sigmoid()
          )
          (3): ConvNormActivation(
            (0): Conv2d(480, 112, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
            (1): BatchNorm2d(112, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
          )
        )
        (stochastic_depth): StochasticDepth(p=0.1, mode=row)
      )
      (1): MBConv(
        (block): Sequential(
          (0): ConvNormActivation(
            (0): Conv2d(112, 672, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
            (1): BatchNorm2d(672, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
            (2): SiLU(inplace=True)
          )
          (1): ConvNormActivation(
            (0): Conv2d(672, 672, kernel_size=(5, 5), stride=(1, 1), padding=(2, 2), groups=672, bias=False)
            (1): BatchNorm2d(672, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
            (2): SiLU(inplace=True)
          )
          (2): SqueezeExcitation(
            (avgpool): AdaptiveAvgPool2d(output_size=1)
            (fc1): Conv2d(672, 28, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1))
            (fc2): Conv2d(28, 672, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1))
            (activation): SiLU(inplace=True)
            (scale_activation): Sigmoid()
          )
          (3): ConvNormActivation(
            (0): Conv2d(672, 112, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
            (1): BatchNorm2d(112, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
          )
        )
        (stochastic_depth): StochasticDepth(p=0.1125, mode=row)
      )
      (2): MBConv(
        (block): Sequential(
          (0): ConvNormActivation(
            (0): Conv2d(112, 672, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
            (1): BatchNorm2d(672, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
            (2): SiLU(inplace=True)
          )
          (1): ConvNormActivation(
            (0): Conv2d(672, 672, kernel_size=(5, 5), stride=(1, 1), padding=(2, 2), groups=672, bias=False)
            (1): BatchNorm2d(672, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
            (2): SiLU(inplace=True)
          )
          (2): SqueezeExcitation(
            (avgpool): AdaptiveAvgPool2d(output_size=1)
            (fc1): Conv2d(672, 28, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1))
            (fc2): Conv2d(28, 672, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1))
            (activation): SiLU(inplace=True)
            (scale_activation): Sigmoid()
          )
          (3): ConvNormActivation(
            (0): Conv2d(672, 112, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
            (1): BatchNorm2d(112, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
          )
        )
        (stochastic_depth): StochasticDepth(p=0.125, mode=row)
      )
    )
    (6): Sequential(
      (0): MBConv(
        (block): Sequential(
          (0): ConvNormActivation(
            (0): Conv2d(112, 672, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
            (1): BatchNorm2d(672, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
            (2): SiLU(inplace=True)
          )
          (1): ConvNormActivation(
            (0): Conv2d(672, 672, kernel_size=(5, 5), stride=(2, 2), padding=(2, 2), groups=672, bias=False)
            (1): BatchNorm2d(672, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
            (2): SiLU(inplace=True)
          )
          (2): SqueezeExcitation(
            (avgpool): AdaptiveAvgPool2d(output_size=1)
            (fc1): Conv2d(672, 28, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1))
            (fc2): Conv2d(28, 672, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1))
            (activation): SiLU(inplace=True)
            (scale_activation): Sigmoid()
          )
          (3): ConvNormActivation(
            (0): Conv2d(672, 192, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
            (1): BatchNorm2d(192, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
          )
        )
        (stochastic_depth): StochasticDepth(p=0.1375, mode=row)
      )
      (1): MBConv(
        (block): Sequential(
          (0): ConvNormActivation(
            (0): Conv2d(192, 1152, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
            (1): BatchNorm2d(1152, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
            (2): SiLU(inplace=True)
          )
          (1): ConvNormActivation(
            (0): Conv2d(1152, 1152, kernel_size=(5, 5), stride=(1, 1), padding=(2, 2), groups=1152, bias=False)
            (1): BatchNorm2d(1152, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
            (2): SiLU(inplace=True)
          )
          (2): SqueezeExcitation(
            (avgpool): AdaptiveAvgPool2d(output_size=1)
            (fc1): Conv2d(1152, 48, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1))
            (fc2): Conv2d(48, 1152, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1))
            (activation): SiLU(inplace=True)
            (scale_activation): Sigmoid()
          )
          (3): ConvNormActivation(
            (0): Conv2d(1152, 192, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
            (1): BatchNorm2d(192, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
          )
        )
        (stochastic_depth): StochasticDepth(p=0.15000000000000002, mode=row)
      )
      (2): MBConv(
        (block): Sequential(
          (0): ConvNormActivation(
            (0): Conv2d(192, 1152, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
            (1): BatchNorm2d(1152, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
            (2): SiLU(inplace=True)
          )
          (1): ConvNormActivation(
            (0): Conv2d(1152, 1152, kernel_size=(5, 5), stride=(1, 1), padding=(2, 2), groups=1152, bias=False)
            (1): BatchNorm2d(1152, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
            (2): SiLU(inplace=True)
          )
          (2): SqueezeExcitation(
            (avgpool): AdaptiveAvgPool2d(output_size=1)
            (fc1): Conv2d(1152, 48, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1))
            (fc2): Conv2d(48, 1152, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1))
            (activation): SiLU(inplace=True)
            (scale_activation): Sigmoid()
          )
          (3): ConvNormActivation(
            (0): Conv2d(1152, 192, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
            (1): BatchNorm2d(192, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
          )
        )
        (stochastic_depth): StochasticDepth(p=0.1625, mode=row)
      )
      (3): MBConv(
        (block): Sequential(
          (0): ConvNormActivation(
            (0): Conv2d(192, 1152, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
            (1): BatchNorm2d(1152, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
            (2): SiLU(inplace=True)
          )
          (1): ConvNormActivation(
            (0): Conv2d(1152, 1152, kernel_size=(5, 5), stride=(1, 1), padding=(2, 2), groups=1152, bias=False)
            (1): BatchNorm2d(1152, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
            (2): SiLU(inplace=True)
          )
          (2): SqueezeExcitation(
            (avgpool): AdaptiveAvgPool2d(output_size=1)
            (fc1): Conv2d(1152, 48, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1))
            (fc2): Conv2d(48, 1152, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1))
            (activation): SiLU(inplace=True)
            (scale_activation): Sigmoid()
          )
          (3): ConvNormActivation(
            (0): Conv2d(1152, 192, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
            (1): BatchNorm2d(192, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
          )
        )
        (stochastic_depth): StochasticDepth(p=0.17500000000000002, mode=row)
      )
    )
    (7): Sequential(
      (0): MBConv(
        (block): Sequential(
          (0): ConvNormActivation(
            (0): Conv2d(192, 1152, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
            (1): BatchNorm2d(1152, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
            (2): SiLU(inplace=True)
          )
          (1): ConvNormActivation(
            (0): Conv2d(1152, 1152, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), groups=1152, bias=False)
            (1): BatchNorm2d(1152, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
            (2): SiLU(inplace=True)
          )
          (2): SqueezeExcitation(
            (avgpool): AdaptiveAvgPool2d(output_size=1)
            (fc1): Conv2d(1152, 48, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1))
            (fc2): Conv2d(48, 1152, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1))
            (activation): SiLU(inplace=True)
            (scale_activation): Sigmoid()
          )
          (3): ConvNormActivation(
            (0): Conv2d(1152, 320, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
            (1): BatchNorm2d(320, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
          )
        )
        (stochastic_depth): StochasticDepth(p=0.1875, mode=row)
      )
    )
    (8): ConvNormActivation(
      (0): Conv2d(320, 1280, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
      (1): BatchNorm2d(1280, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
      (2): SiLU(inplace=True)
    )
  )
  (avgpool): AdaptiveAvgPool2d(output_size=1)
  (classifier): Sequential(
    (0): Dropout(p=0.2, inplace=True)
    (1): Linear(in_features=1280, out_features=1000, bias=True)
  )
)
```

So, basically I changed all the batch norm layers into group norm layers. Each GN layer has 32 as num_groups and the number of channels is exactly the same of batch norm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved: basically, `num_channels` must be divisible by `num_groups`, so I used 8 in each layer rather than 32 as `num_groups`.